# is it possible to tag a post/photo using ios social framework?

Tags: iphone, facebook-sdk-3.0

In my app I need to tag my photo/posts. Is this possible using social framework or Should I use `Facebook-sdk` for this?. Also can I get friends list from social framework? any help to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Tagging a photo or post can only be done using the FacebookSDK for iOS while getting your friends list is possible using both the SocialFramework and the FacebookSDK for iOS.

You can use this code to get your friends list using the SocialFramework.

```
- (void)getFbFriends
{
    ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey: facebookAppId,
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"],
                              ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                              };

    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                   options:options
                                completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
                                    if(granted)
                                    {
                                        NSArray *accounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                        ACAccount *facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

                                        NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];
                                        SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                                                            URL:meurl
                                                                                     parameters:nil];
                                        merequest.account = facebookAccount;

                                        NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];

                                        SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                                                requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                                                          URL:requestURL parameters:@{@"fields":@"id,name,picture,first_name,last_name,gender"}];

                                        request.account = facebookAccount;


                                        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                                                                             NSError *error) {

                                            if(!error)
                                            {
                                                NSDictionary *list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

                                                if([list objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
                                                {
                                                    // if error occured e.g. Invalid Auth etc.
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    NSMutableArray *FBFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                                    [FBFriends addObject:[userInfo objectForKey:@"id"]];
                                                    NSLog(@"friends %@", list);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                NSLog(@"Error");
                                            }

                                        }];
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"Error grant access");
                                    }
                                }];

}
```

Comment: but I could post text/image using social framework. it was successful.

Comment: Yup, You can post an image, text or the comnbination of the two using the SocialFramework. The SocialFramework have some limitations and one of those is photo tagging. Please refer to their documentation.